# Nightwatch.js cannot run on Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nightwatch.js, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to run my e2e test on Jenkins Pipeline, but I meet this problem

```
Error: ChromeDriver process exited with code: 127
   node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
 node_modules/chromedriver/lib/chromedriver/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

this is my Jenkinsfile and I am using node:10, I am also using headless mode, which is shown below

```
pipeline {
agent none
stages {
    stage ('Node image') {
        agent { docker { image 'node:10' } }
        stages {
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                    sh "npm install"
                }
            }
            stage('Build and Test') {
                steps {
                    checkout scm
                    sh "npm test"                        
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

}

```
"chromeOptions" : {
        "args": [
          "window-size=1920,1080",
          "headless",
          "disable-gpu",
        ]
```

So I would like to ask what should I do next? Should I manually install "libnss3" or in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: were you able to fix this?

Comment: no, I still cannot fix it

Comment: @Raju I fixed it by added sh "apt-get update && apt-get install libnss3"

Comment: Hi @Oanh, Great that you were able to fix it.

Comment: @Raju thank you. Now, unfortunately, I meet new problem lol. It says cannot find Chrome binary. I don't know if it is because the image I use, which is Node:10, or not